# Unknown part identification

Tags: identification

I am salvaging parts from a broken VCR and pulled off this. Unfortunately, I was not able to see what was written on the PCB next to it. The code written on the side is either S083 or SO83. I searched this on Digikey and couldn't find a match.[image]

Comment: That's a clock crystal. Probably for the clock function.

Comment: Which means it's probably 32768kHz, but only probably.

Answer (score 2):

That is a clock crystal, and based on the shape it is most likely a 32768 Hz tuning fork type crystal for real time clock timekeeping circuitry.